# mpd watchdog on raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi3, mpd

I would like to use mpd-watchdog from JackRichardson (https://discourse.mopidy.com/t/radio-doesnt-return-after-internet-dropout-mpd-watchdog/424/8) on a raspbian-buster-lite . Copying the files to the relevant directories is no problem. Only update-rc.d mpd-watchdog defaults I think that's something for debian. The question is does this work on a raspberry? Or how should I do this for a raspberry.

Or doesn't work this script at all on a raspberry?

Comment: You may want to consider asking here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have placed my question also there.